# C++ template - variadic templates & pass by const reference

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference, variadic-templates

I have a `ThreadPool` class with an `enqueue` function:

```
class ThreadPool
{
public:
    //(Code removed here)

    template <typename ... Args, typename Fun>
    JobId enqueue(Fun func, Args ... args);

    //(Code removed here)
}
```

And I use it on these non static member function `loadStuff` on class `Object`:

```
class Object
{
    //(Code removed here)
    void init(const PrepareData & prepareData);
    virtual bool loadStuff(const PrepareData & prepareData);
    //(Code removed here)
}
```

by calling in QObject::init :

```
void QObject::init(const PrepareData &prepareData)
{
    threadPool->enqueue(&loadStuff, this, prepareData);
}
```

But I noticed that prepareData was passed by copy, which eats significant memory and slows down significantly the program (and is useless).

So I deleted the copy ctor and assignment operator in PrepareData. The program does not compile anymore, as the variadic template takes its parameters by value and not by reference.

So I declared enqueue to pass the variadic template arguments by reference:

```
template <typename ... Args, typename Fun>
JobId enqueue(Fun func, Args&... args);
```

Now the copy constructor is not called anymore, but I get the following error:

> object.cpp:21: error: no matching function for call to
>
> 'ThreadPool::enqueue(bool (Object::*)(const PrepareData&), Object *,
>   const PrepareData&)'
>   threadPool->enqueue(&prepareType, this, loadStuff);

So I'm quite lost on how to do this. I could, instead of passing a `const PrepareData &`, pass a `const PrepareData *` by copy, but I would like to understand why it does not work with a const reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
template <typename ... Args, typename Fun>
JobId enqueue(Fun func, Args ... args);
```

copies all the `args` because they're all passed by value. There seems to be some confusion with how argument passing works - it doesn't matter that you're calling `enqueue` with a reference to const, it matters that `enqueue` takes its argument by value. `init()` is pass by reference, but `enqueue()` is not.

What you probably want instead is to pass a reference wrapper to your data (by value):

```
threadPool->enqueue(&loadStuff, this, std::ref(prepareData));
```

This will avoid copying `prepareData` and call `loadStuff()` correctly. This also puts the onus on the caller of `enqueue()` to know which things should be copied and which should be referred to.

---

Although, `QObject` needs to ensure that `prepareData` lasts long enough. We take it by reference to `const`, so it doesn't seem like it has any way of doing that. So perhaps an alternative approach would be have `init()` take its data by value:

```
void QObject::init(PrepareData prepareData)
{
    threadPool->enqueue(&loadStuff, this, std::move(prepareData));
}
```

Comment: Things shipped off to a thread pool *should* be by value by default to avoid lifetime issues. If the OP wants reference semantics, they could use a `reference_wrapper`.

Comment: @T.C. Good point, didn't think about what `enqueue()` was doing.

Comment: @T.C. : I understand your concern, but here the PrepareData is a bunch of large const datasets that should really not be copied. I ensure that it stays there until all the thread pool functions remain, in fact threadPool and prepareData are two members of a larger class which ensures this.

Comment: Regarding the last option, that's absolutely impossible : a large amount of Objects enqueue init on the thread pool, and PrepareData is not an object which will be used once, but a single large bunch of data which will be used read-only by all Objects.

Comment: @galinette That's fine - that's a lot of information specific to your situation that doesn't appear in the question. I'm not saying you MUST do this. There are other cases where you would prefer to move it.

Comment: Subsidiary question : would it be possible to use std::forward here?